# jboss 7 as- unable to see jboss sample site or admin interface even after jboss has started

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am a newbie to working with jboss 7 as- I recently set it up on my server, and am able to start it as well.

However after starting it, when I access

```
   http://IP_ADDRESS:8080
```

or

```
   http://IP_ADDRESS:9990
```

Google Chrome gives an error that the page is unavailable.

How can such access be enabled? Also, I am using the startup-shutdown script for /etc/init.d as provided with jboss, do I have to modify the startup and shutdown commands in it, for enabling remote web access to the server interface?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `http://localhost:8080`? If you're using the IP address of your PC it's probably the firewall that is blocking the access to it.

Comment: @JamesRPerkins the setup of jboss is on a centos VPS- I have not installed a GUI on that VPS- do I need to do that now? Can I not access the centos VPS remotely from my PC? thanks...

Comment: Ah, in that case it could be that AS 7 is not being bound to the correct address. Try launching it with `-b 0.0.0.0`.